# twitter client that can use rest api key/secret

Tags: windows, linux, android, desktop-client, twitter

As part of a security research, I have probably found the api credential of large company’s twitter account *(basically, I can post a everyone reset your passwords message)*.
In order to confirm this, I need to test the api secret key.

I know nothing about the twitter api and I don’t even have a twitter account.

So is there a twitter client *(even web based)* that provide a nice interface to the twitter rest api and don’t require account login/passwords ?

Here’s all I have in company_product.rb *(keys have been modified but the length is the same)* :

```
company.session_secret = '688b836c1b24247e60fdd3dc5e64503e'

company.twitter_key     = 'csdkuObsqlSRVl889lcDmA'
company.twitter_secret  = 'D96Uicp3l3lVa8gT4WfBGqpdhrtSs8K08HMWf1Ts'
```